# Show method parameters/prototype in PhpStorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

Is there a way to see a method definition (parameters/prototype) in PhpStorm? I'm thinking of something similar to the way eclipse shows method declarations. [image: eclipse method declaration]

Answer (score 1):

**View | Quick Documentation** for method description and info on parameters.

**View | Quick Definition** to see actual method definition (code).